# Open url when certain conditions are met

Tags: python, html, html-table

I am a newbie in Python. I am building a web scraping tool that could open a URL in an HTML cell after criteria have been fulfilled. Any kind of help would be useful. Thanks!

This is the HMTL code that I am working on:

```
<td data-href="https://www.example.com" data-th="Grade &amp; Rate">
  <div class="green inline-block m-right-10">A2</div>
  <div class="inline-block">16%</div>
</td>
```

I want to open the URL in data-href if the value in **div class="inline-block" is greater than 16%**. I am aware that I have to convert the percentage into a floating number first in order to do that. The thing that I want to know is just how to open the URL.

I am using selenium and beautifulsoup until now to build by script. This is a snapshot of how I built my project.

```
chromedriver = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
....
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
tags = soup('td')
urllist = list()
for tag in tags:
    z = tag.get('data-href','abcde')
    if z not in urllist:
       urllist.append(z)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTMLParser to read the HTML code and urllib.urlretrieve to download the URL.

Comment: I could parse the HTML in the table, I just don't know how to refer back to it when a certain block inside the table match my requirement (greater than 16%).

urllib.urlretrieve is for downloading a page. I want to open it, not downloading it. I use a combination of selenium and beautifulsoup library for my project.

So for example, I am using selenium to open my url using browser.get(url) function